# Finding a sentence in a finite language $\mathcal{L}$ that completely describes a finite $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$.

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Before presenting the actual question, I'd like to emphasize that this question is for an assignment, so **I do not want a full solution**. This is something I need to solve on my own, but I am looking for some guidance in the correct direction. The question is as follows:

> Suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is a finite language, and $\mathcal{M}$ is a finite $\mathcal{L}$-structure. Find an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\phi$ such that given any $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{N}$ if $\mathcal{N} \models \phi$ then $\mathcal{M} \cong \mathcal{N}$.

First, since $\mathcal{M}$ is finite, we know $|M|=n$ for some $n$, so the following $\mathcal{L}$-sentence describes the size of $M$:
$$
\exists x_1,\dots,x_n(\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^n (\bigwedge\limits_{j=1}^n x_i \neq x_j) \land \forall y(\bigvee\limits_{i=1}^n y=x_i))
$$
(I'm aware this sentence is not rigorously written, but my professor has no problems with writing it this way as "we are humans, not computers").

My confusion arises when trying to write out a first-order $\mathcal{L}$-sentence that also preserves the operations of $\mathcal{M}$. I have a feeling there might be some way to do it by somehow writing out how $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are interacting with each other in each relation and function (which is why I imagine $\mathcal{L}$ must be finite), but I'm at a complete loss on how one might do this.

Again, I'm going to reiterate that I am not looking for solutions, only hints. I will post my solution once I solve it.

Thanks for any help.

**Edit**

It is suggested that I write a sentence out for a more concrete example, say the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. We might write:
$$
\exists x_1, \exists x_2 (x_1+x_1=x_1 \land x_1+x_2=x_2 \land x_2+x_1=x_2 \land x_2+x_2=x_1)
$$
This sentence, along with the one above for when $n=2$, completely describes the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. My confusion is more how one might explicitly write a sentence similar to the one above without actually knowing how the functions and relations of the structure are actually interacting with the elements. Could I, without loss of generality, make arbitrary choices for the way in which the functions and relations are interacting with the group?

**Edit 2**
Let us consider the following $\mathcal{L_\textrm{grp}}$-structures
$$
\mathcal{M}=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},+,-,0) \\
\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},+,-,1)
$$
Now, the suggested sentence by commenters and posters would be as follows:
$$
\phi :=\exists x_1,x_2(x_1 \neq x_2 \land \forall y (y=x_1 \lor y=x_2) \land x_1+x_1=x_1 \land x_1+x_2=x_2 \land x_2+x_1=x_2 \land x_2+x_2=x_1)
$$
What I'm curious about is that $\mathcal{M} \models \phi$ and $\mathcal{N} \models \phi$, but $\mathcal{M} \not\cong \mathcal{N}$ since you must map $0$ to $1$ in any isomorphism, and this could not possibly preserve the structure of the group. Note that in $L_{grp}$ the actual structures don't need to actually be groups since there is no theory associated with it.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: $\mathcal L$ is a finite language, so you can completely describe what the operations do on each tuple $(x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k})$. Think about how you describe groups through their multiplication table for instance

Comment: @Max Okay I get that part, my confusion is how one does this for an arbitrary $\mathcal{M}$ since unlike a specific structure, such as the group $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, we don't get a specific table. Is it possible for me to (without loss of generality) assign arbitrary values for each tuple, or would this be an invalid proof?

Comment: Well the structure comes with a specific table : it says what $f(x_1,...x_n)$ is for any tuple $(x_1,...,x_n)$ and any function symbol $f$ : that's what a structure is

Comment: I understand this but what I don't understand is how to write out an explicit sentence without having explicit knowledge of the structure itself. I suppose I could show that such a sentence exists without writing it out explicitly, but I get the feeling that this is not what my professor is looking for.

Comment: Maybe it might be helpful to see an example of what such a sentence might look like if $\mathcal{L}$ is the language of semigroups and $\mathcal{M}$ is the model $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: (Also, technically correct answer to the problem as given, which does not require $\mathcal{M} \models \phi$: $\phi := \bot$.  Or, if your first-order logic's propositional language does not have a built in symbol for the false proposition: $\phi := \lnot (\forall x, x = x)$.)

Comment: For that example, I might write something like $\exists x_0, \exists x_1, [x_0 \ne x_1 \wedge (\forall y, y = x_0 \vee y = x_1) \wedge \\ x_0 + x_0 = x_0 \wedge x_0 + x_1 = x_1 \wedge x_1 + x_0 = x_1 \wedge x_1 + x_1 = x_0]$.

Comment: Yes, that is the sentence I added above (see the edit), but where my confusion arises is when we no longer consider a specific structure, instead of considering an arbitrary one. To me, it seems intuitively obvious that since the language and structure are finite there must be some way of writing a finite sentence that describes how the function is acting on its elements, but I don't see how one would prove this.

Comment: Well, the solution would be essentially the same idea just generalized, it would start with one existential $\exists x_m$ for each $m \in \mathcal{M}$, and then a piece of it could look something like $\bigwedge_{m, n \in \mathcal{M}} (x_m + x_n = x_{m+n})$.

Comment: Wow thank you that might be one of the most brilliant things I've ever seen.

Comment: @DanielSchepler See my newest edit.

Comment: In your newest edit, you forgot that the sentence $\phi$ should talk about constant symbols as well. And relation symbols as well. So your $\phi$ should contain $x_1=c$ or something (where $c$ is a constant symbol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just be having a hard time making it precise and general.

If the structure $\mathcal A$ has domain $A = \{a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n\}$ and we have some function symbol $f$ with arity $n,$ and $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, define $X_f(\sigma)$ to be the unique $m\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $f^{\mathcal A}(a_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, a_{\sigma(n)}) = a_m.$ Then you can take care of the function symbols by appending to your conjunction the conjunction of $$ \bigcup_{f\in \mathcal F}\left\{f(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, x_{\sigma(\mathrm{arity}(f))}) = x_{X_f(\sigma)}: \sigma\in S_{\mathrm{arity}(f)}\right\}$$ where $\mathcal F$ is the set of function symbols in $\mathcal A$'s language. The relations can be handled similarly. I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Check out my edit, I have a few concerns.

Comment: @Dastur A constant symbol is just a $0$-ary function symbol and so is covered by what I wrote. For instance if $0^{\mathcal A} =a_1$ we need to append the sentence $0=x_1.$